# How do I Click a JButton without the user Clicking it?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a JButton and when a player clicks it it tell my Action Listener that a button is clicked. What i want to know is that is there a command or something that acts as if a player clicked the button.

Like Tic Tac Toe, i have it so 2 players can play against each other, but i want to add the option for a computer player vs a human player. But since the computer cant actually click the button, i am lost.

Edit:
would it be as easy as `gridButton2.click()` (Name of button).click();

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pretty much. All you need to do is use the `doClick()` function. See [the API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick()) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

for the tic-tac-toe thing, you don't need the computer to click a button. you just have to wait until the human makes a move, then have the computer choose its move and execute the code that happens if the button gets clicked.

Comment: I think the same as @Andbdrew. If you are sure you cannot go without simulating the click programmatically then use doClick() otherwise if you are only after the functionality do it by introducing a common function that will be called by computer move and player's click.

Answer (score 3):

Just call directly the `actionPerformed()` method from the `ActionListener`implementing class. You can do it the following way:

```
actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(gridButton2, ActionEvent.ACTION_FIRST, "youractioncommand"));
```